# How to choose a sibling node of a html element?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
import React, {useEffect, useContext, useState} from 'react';
import {FormContext} from "../../../core/context";

export default function Todo(props) {
    const { todos, setTodos, deleteTodo, onEditSubmit, editContent, setEditContent} = useContext(FormContext);
    const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {

    }, [isEditing])

    return (
        <div className={todoCard(props.todo)} id="todo-card">
            <div className="card-body d-flex align-items-center">
                <input type="checkbox" className="mx-2"
                       onChange={() => props.toggleCompleted(props.index)}
                       checked={props.todo.isCompleted}/><span className={props.todo.isCompleted ? 'line-through mr-auto': 'mr-auto'}>{props.todo.content}</span>
                <i className={editIcon()} id="edit" onClick={(e) => editTodo(e)}></i>
                <i onClick={() => deleteTodo(props.todo.id)} className="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg" id="trash-o"></i>
            </div>

            <div style={{display: 'none'}} className='card-footer m-0 p-0 justify-content-center'>
                <form className="p-2 d-flex" onSubmit={(e) => onEditSubmit(e, props.todo.id)}>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control mx-2" onChange={(e) => setEditContent(e.target.value)} />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" className="btn btn-warning"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );

    function editIcon() {
        let baseline = 'fa fa-pencil-square-o mx-3';
        if (isEditing) baseline += 'editing';
        return baseline;
    }

    function editTodo(e) {
       const cardFooter = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[1];
        cardFooter.style.display === 'none' ? cardFooter.style.display = 'flex': cardFooter.style.display = 'none';
    }

    function todoCard(item) {
        let className = 'card';
        if (item.isFound) className += 'text-white bg-info';
        return className;
    }
}
```

On the first line of the editTodo() function I'm selecting the card footer of the exact instance of the todo that I'm trying to edit. I would like to know if there are any alternatives to doing this(The first line of the function). Because if my elements  were much deeply nested then it would be a pain to select a sibling node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are two options.

1. By native javascript and react, you can pass variable when you call your function i.e. (`editTodo(myIdVar)`). You need to generate a specific ID that is unique (before the return), pass it to your `editTodo` then use it to search for that by ID (`document.getElementById('myUniqueId')`). This is the best solution because it will directly point a specific item, however, for this, you need a unique ID.
2. You pull in jQuery, and it has a parent function that goes up for a specific tag (i.e. `$(element).parent('div.myclass')` will look for a `div` tag that has a `myclass` class on it) after then you can go down by selecting a class or telling a child item. You can get the `element` by wrapping the `e.target` like `$(e.target)` or any other Javascript DOM object. This solution doesn't need unique id, it's more dynamic than your solution but it costs little more time to execute.